# .netcore I want to pull 500 kafka messages at once, how do I configure

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka

I want to pull 500 messages at once, how should I configure it in `ConsumerConfig`.
The Nuget package I use is Confluent.Kafka 1.4.3.0 version, I tried to set its `MaxPartitionFetchBytes = 5 * 1024 * 1024` but it did not achieve the effect I wanted.

Comment: In the Java API, at least, this is the default poll size